# USB Port binding to application - Windows

Tags: visual-c++, usb

I wrote application that communicates with specific USB devices (Video encoder).
The device itself does not allow to get the device ID, so if I connect two devices I can not identify them. Solution now is to have as many PCs as I have USB devices (encoders)

I would like to know how to be able to dedicate one USB port per application.

To ilustrate how I have now

```
[Device 1] - [PC 1] - [USB Port 1] - [Application 1]
[Device 2] - [PC 2] - [USB Port 1] - [Application 1]
[Device 3] - [PC 3] - [USB Port 1] - [Application 1]
```

How I would like to have

```
[Device 1] \            / [USB Hub / USB Port 1] - [Application 1]
[Device 2]  -- [PC 1] --  [USB Hub / USB Port 2] - [Application 2]
[Device 3] /            \ [USB Hub / USB Port 3] - [Application 3]
```

I would like to create like this (pseudocode)

```
main(){

    attachApplicationToUsbPort('USB Hub / USB Port 1')

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE);

    result = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CBMDStreamingDiscovery, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IBMDStreamingDiscovery, (void**)&m_streamingDiscovery);

    ...
    ...
}
```

Now I would open three applications and assign each application to specific port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of APIs you are using to access that USB device, but every device in Windows has a unique identifier called a [Device Instance ID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff541327).  For a USB device without a serial number, the Device Instance ID will look something like this:

```
USB\VID_51AD&PID_7D8B\6&11A23516&18&0000
```

I believe the part after the second back slash should be a function of what port you plug the device into, and I think it should not change when you reboot.  You should be able to use that to assign a process to a specific USB device, as long as that device is always plugged into the same port.

I think that's the easy way to do it.  On the other hand, if you really want to start dealing with USB hubs and ports in your code, you might take a look at the code for [USBView](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/USBView-sample-application-e3241039) from Microsoft.

Comment: Thank you. I must find a way now how to assign this "Device Instance ID" to specific instance of program. Would you have some idea as-well?

Comment: The hard part is getting the ids and later selecting a device based on the id.  Assigning is easy.  I don't know how your app is configured, but you could add the id to a configuration file or pass it as a command line argument.

Comment: You can use SetupAPI to list devices and get their IDs.  It's hard to give more specific advice than that.

Comment: Perfect, I did not know about theSetupAPI. You said "assigning is easy". Would you be so kind and please let me know how? As you see from my semi-pseudocode above, I'm using CoInitializeEx and CoCreateInstance to create USB hooks for my application.

Comment: To me, assigning means passing a device instance id to your program.  Actually using the id might be harder.  Maybe there is some part of the code you are not showing where you you select which USB device to use.  Any good USB API must provide a feature for that, and I don't think you have shown the relevant code.

Comment: It's hard for me to imagine the parts of your code that select a USB device and then give you good instructions for modifying them.

Comment: I agree. I'm using BlackMagic device, ProRecorder and their API does not support unique identifier and they will not support it. Therefore I try to find some other solution
https://github.com/baycom/MXPTiny/blob/master/MXPTinyDlg.cpp#L173
Here for example is software that is using this API for this device. These two are, for what I believe, functions that makes application starts to listen to USB device changes, and when device is connected then StreamingDeviceArrived method is called, but device does not have unique identifier ...

Comment: Where is the documentation of `IDeckLink` or `IID_IBMDStreamingDeviceInput`?  Do either of them have a function for getting a Device Instance ID?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0boC5wj9JcMYnhDUkQteHJjQjg/view?usp=sharing I uploaded here the latest one.
I did use the setupapi to go through devices, I get the device and the SP_DEVINFO_DATA for this device but I'm not sure if I can now convert DevInst to IDeckLink* device that StreamingDeviceArrived method needs.
They do have BMDDeckLinkPersistentID and BMDDeckLinkTopologicalID in API but is not implemented for this device.

Comment: Well I glanced at the document but I don't see anything obvious.  This started off as a question about how to work with USB devices in Windows and has now morphed into a question about how to navigate some third-party API.  I am not familiar with that API, but you should probably ask the people who developed it, since this is probably a common issue.  Their API is probably using SetupAPI under the hood and you just need them to expose the Device Instance ID of each USB device so you can select them based on that.